# Google table chart issue with query containing LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

I am having an issue when trying to visualize some data using [google table charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table). My data source is a mysql db while the php code I am using to connect to my database and to get data is the [standard php code](https://codeday.me/es/qa/20181202/15188.html) (see the example/section called "PHP-PDO-JSON-MySQL-Google"). Both mysql db and php run on a VPS. The odd behavior appears when I use LIMIT in my query. Specifically, I am able to display my table only if LIMIT x with x <= 5:

OK

```
$result_RTI_VS_W_TABLE = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `video_series_rank_week` ORDER BY `Year` DESC, `WeekN` DESC, `Rank` ASC LIMIT 5");
```

NOT OK

```
$result_RTI_VS_W_TABLE = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `video_series_rank_week` ORDER BY `Year` DESC, `WeekN` DESC, `Rank` ASC LIMIT 8");
```

Note that the query with LIMIT 8 works on phpmyadmin as expected. So, data exists. During some experiments, I have also noticed that queries with different LIMIT statements to visualize [google line charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) seem to work correctly. This, to my mind, should be a problem with table charts instead of with the queries. In addition, the same code works on my old VPS.

Any ideas why I am getting this strange output?

code:

```
  <head>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        // Load the Visualization API and the table package.
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

        function drawTable() {

          // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
          var data_RTI_VS_W_TABLE = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable_RTI_VS_W_TABLE?>);

          // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
          // Do not forget to check your div ID
          var table_RTI_VS_W_TABLE = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div_RTI_VS_W_TABLE'));
          table_RTI_VS_W_TABLE.draw(data_RTI_VS_W_TABLE, {showRowNumber: false, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
        }
        </script>

  </head>
```

**Requested additional info**:

```
<?php

    try {
      /* Establish the database connection */
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      /* select relevant info for table googlechart */
      $result_RTI_VS_W_TABLE = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `video_series_rank_week` ORDER BY `Year` DESC, `WeekN` DESC, `Rank` ASC LIMIT 8");

      $rows_RTI_VS_W_TABLE = array();
      $table_RTI_VS_W_TABLE = array();
      $table_RTI_VS_W_TABLE['cols'] = array(

        /* Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles */
        array('label' => 'Rank', 'type' => 'number'),
        array('label' => 'Year', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => 'WeekN', 'type' => 'number'),
        array('label' => 'Series Name', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => 'Total Historical Constrained Ad Avails', 'type' => 'number')
    );
        /* Extract the information from $result */
        foreach($result_RTI_VS_W_TABLE as $r_RTI_VS_W_TABLE) {

        $temp_RTI_VS_W_TABLE = array();

       /* the following line will be used to get a table */
        $temp_RTI_VS_W_TABLE[] = array('v' => (int) $r_RTI_VS_W_TABLE['Rank']);

       /* Values */
        $temp_RTI_VS_W_TABLE[] = array('v' => (string) $r_RTI_VS_W_TABLE['Year']);
        $temp_RTI_VS_W_TABLE[] = array('v' => (int) $r_RTI_VS_W_TABLE['WeekN']);
        $temp_RTI_VS_W_TABLE[] = array('v' => (string) $r_RTI_VS_W_TABLE['Series Name']);
        $temp_RTI_VS_W_TABLE[] = array('v' => (int) $r_RTI_VS_W_TABLE['Total Historical Constrained Ad Avails']);

        $rows_RTI_VS_W_TABLE[] = array('c' => $temp_RTI_VS_W_TABLE);}

        $table_RTI_VS_W_TABLE['rows'] = $rows_RTI_VS_W_TABLE;

    /* convert data into JSON format */
    $jsonTable_RTI_VS_W_TABLE = json_encode($table_RTI_VS_W_TABLE);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();}
    ?>
```

**UPDATE**:

After some other experiments, I have found that my issue is strictly related to the string nature of the field "Series Name", i.e.

```
array('label' => 'Series Name', 'type' => 'string')
```

It is like google table chart is not able to display that column after the 5th row.. If I indeed drop that column I have no issue anymore. Ideas???

Thanks in advance.

Drigo

**SOLVED**
I had to add:

```
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
```

to my new PDO.

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

Comment: will you please share a sample of --> `$jsonTable_RTI_VS_W_TABLE`

Comment: not sure I have posted what you asked for...